# d3js Multiline ... How can I have the Y values?

Tags: d3.js

I am using this sample that is very nice ...

http://bl.ocks.org/aiMojica10/7a3a9233f3bcd60f0c3935c5875e850d

Partidos followers

or the sample ...

http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/44ffca2877d0132572cb

We can see the values of "Y" being updated as we move the mouse. But, I would like to know how to display the legend and values at the top of the chart, for example next to the caption "Day:" or "Year" in the samples ?

In other words, I would like all values of Y in separeted variables.

Well, what I need to change in the multiline.js  ?

Thanks,

Comment: In other words, for every "Day", 
I would like all values of Y in separeted variables, as below ...

variableA = progresistascol = "y value" 
variableB = CeDemocraico    = "y value"
variableC = PartidoVerdeCoL = "y value"
variableD = PartidoLiberal  = "y value"
variableE = somosRegion     = "y value"
variableF = PoderCiudadanos = "y value"
variableG = PCambioRadical  = "y value"

Well, what I need to change in the multiline.js  ?